# Karate API Testing - Reusing variables in different scenarios in the same feature file

Tags: karate

Does Karate supports a feature where you can define a variable in a scenario and reuse it in other scenarios in the same feature file. I tried doing the same but get an error. What's the best way to reuse the variables within the same feature file ?

```
Scenario: Get the request Id
    * url baseUrl
    Given path 'eam'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And def reqId = response.teams[0]resourceRequestId

Scenario: Use the above generated Id
   * url baseUrl
   * print 'From the previous Scenario: ' + reqId
```

Error:

```
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "reqId" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `Background:` section. Here is an [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/greeting/greeting.feature).

EDIT: the variable if in the `Background:` will be re-initialized for every scenario which is standard testing framework "set up" behavior. You can use [hooks such as `callonce`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks) - if you want the initialization to happen only once.

If you are trying to modify a variable in one scenario and expect it to be now having that modified value when the next `Scenario` starts, you have misunderstood the concept of a `Scenario`. Just combine your steps into one `Scenario`, because think about it: that is the "*flow*" you are trying to test.

Each `Scenario` should be able to run **stand-alone**. In the future the execution order of `Scenario`-s could even be random or run in parallel.

Another way to explain this is - if you comment out one `Scenario` other ones should continue to work.

Please don't think of the `Scenario` as a way to "document" the important parts of your test. You can always use comments (e.g. `# foo bar`). Some teams assume that each HTTP "end point" should live in a separate `Scenario` - but this is absolutely not recommended. Look at the [Hello World example](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hello-world) itself, it deliberately shows 2 calls, a `POST` and a `GET` !

You can easily re-use code using [`call`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#call) so you should not be worrying about whether code-duplication will be an issue.

Also - it is fine to have some code duplication, if it makes the flow easier to read. See [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475) - and also read [this article by Google](https://testing.googleblog.com/2019/12/testing-on-toilet-tests-too-dry-make.html).

EDIT: if you would like to read another answer that answers a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59433600/143475

Comment: so if we declare a variable in Background, we can have it updated through one scenario and the updated value can be used by the subsequent scenarios ?

Comment: @PeterThomas how to update background variable? since Background is updated before every scenario , it is will initialised back to the previous variable.

Comment: @PeterThomas, Authorization header didn't get passed to the next request. How to do that?

Comment: @Venkat you really need to read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-header-manipulation