# Karate API Testing - Access variable value across scenario in a feature file

Tags: api, karate

I am running into this situation (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079130/karate-api-testing-reusing-variables-in-different-scenarios-in-the-same-featur)) when trying to do the following:

```
Scenario: Create User
Given path 'user'
    And request read('user.json');
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And def user_id = response.userId

Scenario: Test A
   Given path 'user/' + user_id <- Received javascript error here
   ...

Scenario: Test B
   Given path 'user/' + user_id <- Received javascript error here
   ...

Scenario: Test A
   Given path 'user/' + user_id <- Received javascript error here
   ...
```

Basically what i am trying to do is create a user in my database first, then run it through a series of test and use a last scenario to delete this user. Therefore, i need to share the user_id value across multiple scenarios. Background doesn't work for me because that means i have to create a new user for each scenario. I have seen in the demo that a simple way would be to put all test under 1 scenario but i don't feel that it is right to put all tests on 1 scenario

I have reviewed the karate demo but i did not come across any sample code that will help my situation. May i know the right way to do this in Karate? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the [`callonce`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#callonce) keyword. Understand it and then look at the demos, for example, this one: [`callonce.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callonce/call-once.feature).

You will need to move the 'common' code into a separate feature, but that is the right thing to do, because you will typically want it re-usable by multiple feature files as well.

Comment: Is callonce the only get to share value across scenario within a feature file? Is there any other ways? I tried setting and getting value using js function via the karate object but when retrieving in the new scenario, the set value is not there anymore.

Comment: @david use `callonce` **AND** in a `Background` section. kindly read the doc and example I provided carefully ! all the best.

Comment: Hi Peter, I forgot to add in my earlier reply that i did read the documentations and tried the backgroud+callonce method using the demo app as a guide. It work well for me. Basically i created a AddUser.feature file that added 1 user and passed me back the id to test with the rest of the scenarios.

However, i am wondering if it is possible to contain test setup and teardown code together with the scenarios within the feature file itself, rather than having to write them in a separate file and passing the value back? Maybe i am not thinking about something rightly?

Comment: @david No. I clearly mentioned this in my main answer. If you find writing a separate feature file troublesome, then I can't help you :P

Comment: @david I think you are new here. do you mind up-voting and marking the answer as "accepted" it helps maintain the quality of answers on Stack Overflow. thanks.