# Karate API pass def variable in XML

Tags: xml, api, soap, karate

I defined a variable with

```
* def token = '1bce02b8..'
```

I would like to retrieve the variable I defined so I can pass this to my SOAP request. How can I make this possible?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:isValid>
         <token>$token</token>
      </ws:isValid>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, use [embedded expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions) in the `#(foo)` form, they work for XML as well:

```
* def token = 'foo'
* def payload =
"""
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:isValid>
         <token>#(token)</token>
      </ws:isValid>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""
* print payload
```

Which prints:

```
[print] <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.com">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ws:isValid>
      <token>foo</token>
    </ws:isValid>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I suggest you also refer to this set of examples, specifically for XML that will give you more ideas: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)

Comment: Thank you it's working! But I have the token variable from the previous scenario. The variable token is not accessible on the next scenario, how can I make this global?

Comment: Yes, a common question, please refer to this answer, especially the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630187/143475

Comment: Is it possible to change the global variable in the background?

Comment: For example I have defined a global variable in the background * def Test = 'Hello' and I want to change this global variable in other scenario to Test = 'Welcome'

Comment: No. the point of a `Background` is to guarantee all `Scenario`-s have the same initial state. It sounds like you really need a single `Scenario`. If you really insist on doing this, just call Java and manage your own singleton.

Comment: Thank you for helping me so far. I have one last question. How can I filter only the last variable in the request result. In this case I want the value of the token variable: NUTEST=com.intuit.karate.cucumber.FeatureWrapper@13c3c1e1, responseTime=6, response={soap:Envelope={_={soap:Body={ns2:loginResponse={_={return=a866fb4f-47e4-4895-ac13-2118b6c025c8}, @={xmlns:ns2=http://ws.openkm.com}}}}, @={xmlns:soap=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}}}, responseStatus=200, __loop=-1, responseCookies=null, token=a866fb4f-47e4-4895-ac13-2118b6c025c8}

Comment: I posted a new question thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756777/karate-get-one-variable-from-a-request