# How can is store the value of an element in a API response from one scenario and use the variable in the other scenarios in the same feature file?

Tags: web-api-testing, karate

Consider I am having three scenarios in my feature file. I want an authorization token that I get from an API response in the first scenario to be used in the other scenarios.

I declare the variable in "Background:" section. How to use the variable across scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variable declared in the `Background:` will be available for use in all `Scenario:`s in the same feature.

Refer to this answer for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080568/143475