# Invoke filed from last scenario response failed with karate

Tags: karate

Below is my code, i want to use CartItemId from scenario1 response as request for scenario2, but scenario cannot get its value.

```
    Scenario: /api/wishlist/item/add - add to wishlist 
     Given path '/api/wishlist/item/add' 
     And headers allHeaders.HeadersToken
     And request {"CultureCode":"CHS","IsSpecificSku":0,"MerchantId":"#(data.StyleMerchantId)","SkuId":"#(data.SkuId)","UserKey":"#(data.UserKey)"}
     When method POST
     Then status 200
     * def CartItemId = response.CartItems[0].CartItemId
     * print CartItemId
     * print response

    Scenario: /api/wishlist/item/remove - remove from wishlist 
     Given path '/api/wishlist/item/remove' 
     And headers allHeaders.HeadersToken
     And request {"CartItemId":"#(CartItemId)","CultureCode":"CHS","UserKey":"#(data.UserKey)"}
     When method POST
     Then status 200
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to test a "flow" here which is "first add, then remove". Please combine the two `Scenario`s into one.

Detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080568/143475