# How to iterate multiple feature files in karate

Tags: karate

Feature File 1:inputData.feature

```
     @ignore
     Feature: Input data table
     Scenario: Input table for testing
* table testData
  | accountId           |  accountname    | expectedAccount  |
  | 'ADS5678543'   | 'Peter'              | 'DFCVSAEFRG'     |
  | 'ASDCF45678'   | 'Caroline'           |  'DFCWEAEFRG'    |
```

File 2: payload.json

```
{
"channelData": {
"data": "CHANNEL_DATA",
"salesChannel": "WEB",
"createdBy": "WEBSITE",
"accountId": "#(accountId)",
"sessionId": "#(accountname)"
 }
}
```

File 3: Request.feature

```
@ignore
Feature:

Scenario:
 # read the payload from json file
 * def Request = read('../payload.json')
 * def headersData = { "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
 Given url BaseUrl + '/account/'+'#(accountId)'
 And request Request
 And headers headersData
 When method post
 Then status 200
 * print response
  * def account = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.account")
 * print 'account is '+account
 Then match account == '#(expectedAccount)'
```

File 4: addressinfo.feature

```
@ignore
Feature:

Scenario:
   * def Request = “{
     “accountId": "#(resAccount)”
    }
 ”
 * def headersData = { "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
 Given url BaseUrl +'#(resAccount)’+'/address’
 And request Request
 And headers headersData
 When method post
 Then status 200
 * print response
```

File5: Account-token.feature

```
  Feature: 
Scenario: identify the reference account
 * def initTestData = read('../inputData.feature')
 * def reqRes = karate.call('../Request.feature', { initTestData : initTestData })
 * def resAccount =  $reqRes[*].account // output of this is [“SB987658”,”SB984345”]
 * def addressData = read('../addressinfo.feature’,{resAccount: resAccount})
```

In the above scenario, we have to pass the output of Request.feature as input to addressing.feature. java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 34:  http://10.36.145.196:9983/invoker/[“SB987658”,”SB984345”]/address . Our requirement is it should iterate each value of resAccount and we need to pass the o/p response of addressinfo.feature as I/p to another feature file.

Comment: please read this before asking your next question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule for `call` args that need to be looped is that it has to be an array of JSONs. Refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

So you can transform the primitive array, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

```
* def resAccountList = karate.map(resAccount, function(x){ return { resAccount: x } })
```

I have to say your tests are badly designed and will cause you maintenance problems in the future. Try to avoid "too much reuse" and avoid `call` as far as possible. Refer to this answer for why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Comment: I have tried * def fun = function(x){ return { testcaseName: x } }
            * def resAccountList = karate.map(resAccount, fun)                                                                
            * def addressData = read('../addressinfo.feature’)resAccountList.resAccount .In addressinfo.feature when i try to print the * print "Calling scenario feature:"+ resAccountList.resAccount . it is printed as undefined. My requirement is ,When I hit first request I will get response [“SB987658”,”SB984345”] , I want to run another feature file by pass each value as inputparameter.

Comment: @MurugeshSubramaniam sorry I can't read and understand this and as I commented below your question it is too complex. here is my last piece of advice, all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Still, my issue is not resolved. I am closing this issue and create a new with details.