# Karate: When sending jsonPath to another feature, 'set' function don't see that jsonPath

Tags: karate

I have two feature: first where I have arguments and second where I want to send argumnets from first feature.

First feature:

```
Feature: test
@dev
  Scenario: test

    * def arguments = { value: '123.00', jspath: '..transferData.amount',consent_body: 'classpath:consent_domestic.json' }
    * def createConsentResult = call read('classpath:reuseable/features/changeConsentBody.feature') arguments
```

Second feature:

```
@ignore
Feature: Change consent body - 1 parameter

  Background:
    * url ''
    * call read('classpath:reuseable/features/commonFunction.feature')

  @act
  Scenario : Change consent body - 1 parameter

    * path 'consents'
    * def consentBody = read(consent_body)
    * print "jsonPath: "+jspath
    * set consentBody jspath= value
    When request consentBody
    And method post
    Then status 201
```

Here `* def consentBody = read(consent_body)` karate sees 'consent_body' as a variable and uses value of this variable.

Here `* print "jsonPath: "+jspath` karate sees 'jspath' as a variable and uses value of this variable and print: `[print] jsonPath: ..transferData.amount`.

**BUT** here `* set consentBody jspath = value` karate doesn't see 'jspath' as a variable and doesn't use the value of this variable. Instead , karate shows error:

`changeConsentBody.feature:17 - unexpected path: jspath`

**In this case karate need to see 'jspath' as a variable and use the value of this variable.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two obvious problems here. By the way, please maintain white-space on each side of the `=` sign:

```
* set consentBody jspath = value
```

Variables will not work for the `set` command. And you cannot use JsonPath. If you have dynamic paths, you can do this, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#eval

```
* def foo = {}
* def path = 'bar'
* eval foo[path] = 'baz'
* match foo == { bar: 'baz' }
```

If you want to update an array in "bulk", instead of `..transferData.amount` - please use the [`karate.map()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms) operation:

```
* def foo = [{},{}]
* def fun = function(x){ x.transferData = { amount: 100 }; return x }
* def res = karate.map(foo, fun)
* match res == [{ transferData: { amount: 100 } }, { transferData: { amount: 100 } }]
```

Finally I urge you to read this carefully, try to avoid "generic" test cases and using `call`, it just complicates things un-necessarily: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Comment: one more way would be to use the embedded expression in your `consent_domestic.json`, you can add `'#(value)'` as a value for all the `amount` you want to modify. something like this `{ transferData: { amount: '#(value)'} }`.

Comment: If _'Variables will not work for the set command.'_, then why for 'consentBody' and 'value' it is working? For two of three params it is working and I think it will be logical if it will be working for the third too.

Comment: @cheparsky `set` is useful for 90% of the folks who write simple test cases without trying to be too "generic". if you feel that it is not right, assume that the `set` keyword does not exist and stick to using `eval`.