# Cannot use "==" and "contains" in same line of scenario using conditional logic in Karate

Tags: dsl, karate

This is a follow up of a [question noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187219/karate-ability-to-dynamically-decide-the-type-of-match-in-karate-for-verificat)

Lets says our implemented server v1 and v2 response looks as follows

```
v1Response = { id: "1", name: "awesome" }
v2Response = { id: "2", name: "awesome", value: "karate" }
```

Similarly we define the client schema for v1 and v2 like as follows

```
v1Schema = { id: "#string", name: "#string }
v2Schema = { id: "#string", name: "#string, value: "#string" }
```

We implement schema validation in our generic scenario as follows. We can easily set the "response" with either v1Response/v2Response AND "schema" with either v1Schema/v2Schema depending on our the environment.

```
* match response == schema
```

Above generic script works perfectly fine as long as we are testing v1 server against v1 client / v2 server against v2 client. However we cannot re-use the same scenario when we want to test backward compatibility for example
v2 server against v1 client. In this case

```
* match response (actually v2Response) == schema (actually v1Schema) <--- will fail
```

So in order to make it work and do backward compatibility testing, I also wanted to use karate "contains" feature like

```
* match response (actually v2Response) contains schema (actually v1Schema) <--- will pass
```

However in the quest to keep my scenarios generic it is currently not possible to do either

1. Use both ==/contains in the same line of script like as follows

   - serverVersion == clientVersion ? (match response == schema) : (match response contains schema)

OR

2. Using some flag as follows

   - match response SOMEFLAG schema

whereas SOMEFLAG can be set to either "==" or "contains" in karate-config.js depending on environment we are testing.

EDIT

From the above example, all I want is to test following cases that should pass

```
* match v1Response == v1Schema
* match v2Response == v2Schema 
* match v2Response contains v1Schema
```

using a generic line as following

```
* match response == schema <--- can it possibly be solved using above suggested solutions ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason you feel that hacking the `match` clause is the only way to solve this problem. Please keep an open mind and, here you go:

```
* def schemas =
"""
{
  v1: { id: "#string", name: "#string" },
  v2: { id: "#string", name: "#string", value: "#string" }
}
"""

* def env = 'v1'
* def response = { id: "1", name: "awesome" }
* match response == schemas[env]

* def env = 'v2'
* def response = { id: "2", name: "awesome", value: "karate" }
* match response == schemas[env]

* def response = { id: "1", name: "awesome" }
* match response == karate.filterKeys(schemas[env], response)
```

The last line is as generic as you can get.

Comment: Right, but you are not considering the fact that my v2 server is backward compatible with v1 client hence the need to do following 

`def response = { id: "2", name: "awesome", value: "karate" }`
`match response == schemas['v1']`

Above will not pass, am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Dixie as I mentioned in my other answer I strongly discourage this over-engineering of tests. prefer being specific and readable instead of being "re-usable". but here is the solution for you - see my edit