# karate.filterKeys() API for complex JSON object

Tags: dsl, karate

This question came to my mind after asking [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205643/cannot-use-and-contains-in-same-line-of-scenario-using-conditional-logic/57206396?noredirect=1#comment100925146_57206396)

Lets say my response is a complex array of JSON object and currently I test like this for complex object.

```
* def response = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}.....] 
* def schema = { id: "#number" } 
* match response == '#[] schema'
```

I want to replace above match statement with the use of filerKeys() API possibly like as follows

```
* match response == karate.filterKeys([]schema, response)
```

Basically first parameter of karate.filterKeys() API should dynamically accept every JSON object from response array and filter against the second parameter response for a successful match.

Comment: I re-read your question multiple times and have no idea, giving up. try to provide a *simple* example of the validation you are trying to do.

Comment: Agreed maybe I was not clear enough, I have now edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to dynamically alter your schema for each JSON value in a JSON array.

you can create an equivalent JSON array schema and do a `match ==`

```
* def response = [{id: 1},{id: 2}, {id: 3}] 
* def schema = { id: '#number' } 
* def fun = function(x){ return karate.filterKeys(schema,x) }
* match response == karate.map(response, fun)
```