# Is there a way to match dynamic object keys?

Tags: karate

I'm looking for a simple technique to match objects where the key may not be known in advance (e.g. we may fetch the schema as part of the test). As a contrived example:

```
    Scenario:
        * def result = { foo: 'bar' }
        * def key = 'foo'

        Then match result == { '#(key)': 'bar' }
```

...which doesn't currently work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you realize there is a JavaScript engine behind the scenes, you will get even more ideas :)

```
* def result = { foo: 'bar' }
* def key = 'foo'
* def expected = {}
* expected[key] = 'bar'
Then match result == expected
```

Also do a search for other answers [`[karate] dynamic`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bkarate%5D%20dynamic) you will find many interesting examples such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57226061/143475