dynamic response validation in karate
'we have api which response is below,The keys(humidity,temperature) are dynamic depends upon the request how to Vaildate schema in karate
{   "en_humidity": [
    {
      "value": "48",
      "ts": 1718279604644
    }   ],   "temperature": [
    {
      "value": "decryption failed",
      "ts": 1717580459552
    }   ],   "humidity": [
    {
      "value": "decryption failed",
      "ts": 1718279604644
    }   ] }


First read this. Maybe you should not be trying to do "logic" in your tests. From my experience, it just makes things more complicated, and your tests become less readable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475
But just as an example you can do this.
* def data = []
* karate.forEach(response, (k, v) => data.push(v[0]) )
* match each data == { value: '#string', ts: '#number' }

The first two lines "flatten" the repeating part into a single JSON array, and then your assertion becomes simple. This is explained in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912833/143475 - so you can add any custom logic you want along the same lines.

What about using schema validation type setup like this?
Feature: List of response schemas for validation
  Scenario: Set Schemas
    * def Response =
    """
            ({
            en_humidity: '##(schemaList.ResponseValues)',
            temperature: '##(schemaList.ResponseValues)',
            humidity: '##(schemaList.ResponseValues)'
            })
    """

    * def ResponseValues =
    """
            ({
            ts: '##number',
            value: '##string'
            })
    """

This schema file is called as such in a background or alternate file:

def schemaList = call read('classpath:testdata/responseSchemas.feature')

Usage is like this:

match $ == schemaList.Response

More insight can be found here:  https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#schema-validation
