# Nested JSON response Validation

Tags: api, karate

```
JSON Response

{
Feed[
      {"item_type":"cycle","id":123},
      {"item_type":"computer","name":"mac"},
      {"item_type":"Bag","weight":"2"}
  ]
}

As nested schema is changing based on item type

so can we compare schema based on item type?

example: if item_type is cycle then it should compare with id,
 if item_type is computer then it should compare name like this
```

I have tried with below:

```
* def schema = {item_type:"#string",id:'##number',name: '##string',weight:'##string'}
```

in this schema validation even item_type is cycle and name is mac, test cases will pass but in actual it should fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me recommend that trying to do these extreme "generic" validations may be a waste of time. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

But here is one possible solution, there could be other ways.

Please read the docs and research other answers to understand this properly. This uses a second feature file.

First feature file:

```
* def response = 
"""
[
  { "item_type": "cycle", "id": 123 },
  { "item_type": "computer", "name": "mac" },
  { "item_type": "bag", "weight": "2" }
]
"""
* print response
* def data = 
"""
{
  cycle: { id: '#number' },
  computer: { name: '#string' },
  bag: { weight: '#string' } 
}
"""
* def isValid = function(x){ karate.call('called.feature', x) }
* karate.forEach(response, isValid)
```

Second feature file (called `called.feature`):

```
@ignore
Feature:

Scenario:
* def expected = data[__arg.item_type]
* match __arg contains expected
```