# jsonPath in scenario example

Tags: karate

Could someone help me with below :
Is it possble to use json path expression in the Scenario Outline examples?

Scenario Outline:Verify the path and description

```
Given url
When method GET
* match <path> == <description>

Examples:
|path|description|
|$.parent.child.description|"First child"|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see example below:

```
Scenario Outline:
* def response = { foo: '1', bar: '2' }
* match <path> == '<expected>'

Examples:
| path  | expected |
| $.foo | 1        |
| $.bar | 2        |
```

But I strongly recommend you don't try to do this kind of "clever stuff" since it leads to maintainability issues in the long term. For an example of what I am referring to, see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Karate is very good at matching the *entire* JSON in one step and you will lost that advantage. Also your example has a serious problem because it will make a GET request for *every* row in the table.

So please write one `Scenario` for each "flow" you want to test as far as possible. Do not combine things too much. I am speaking from experience :)