# Passing variables into Examples section

Tags: karate

I have set two variables, let's say cityA = 'New York' and cityB = 'Las Vegas' in one feature and "exported" them with `* def` expression. Now I want to use those variables in another feature

```
Scenario Outline: Successful transfer from <fromLocation> to <toLocation>
    * call read('re-usable.feature')    
    Given request read('request.json')
    When method post
    Then status 200

    Examples:
    | fromLocation | toLocation |
    | cityA | cityB |
    | cityB | cityA |
```

with request:

```
{
source: "#(fromLocation)"
destination: "#(toLocation)"
}
```

My scenarios are failing because in request there is set cityA/cityB, not values stored under these names, I tried to use variables from karate-config file and even

```
Scenario Outline: Successful transfer from <fromLocation> to <toLocation>
    * def res = call read('re-usable.feature')    
    Given request read('request.json')
    When method post
    Then status 200

    Examples:
    | fromLocation | toLocation |
    | res.cityA | res.cityB |
    | res.cityB | res.cityA |
```

and that is passing 'res.cityA', 'res.cityB' instead of New York/Las Vegas
Moreover, I tried also following ways

```
Background:
    * call read('re-usable.feature')
Scenario Outline: Successful transfer from <fromLocation> to <toLocation>

    Given request read('request.json')
    When method post
    Then status 200

    Examples:
    | fromLocation | toLocation |
    | cityA | cityB |
    | cityB | cityA |
```

and

```
Background:
    * def res = call read('re-usable.feature')
Scenario Outline: Successful transfer from <fromLocation> to <toLocation>

    Given request read('request.json')
    When method post
    Then status 200

    Examples:
    | fromLocation | toLocation |
    | res.cityA | res.cityB |
    | res.cityB | res.cityA |
```

All presented cases return the same - varaible names not values. If in the request I set e.g. `#(cityA)` instead of `#(toLocation)` then everything is as expected but I cannot test other scenarios in this case

@PeterThomas you marked my last question as duplicate but link you have provided is not about my issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

Variable "substitution" in `Examples` is not supported. Also you seem to be confused between `fromLocation` and `cityA`, I strongly recommend keeping tests simple, as I [linked to from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475).

Anyway, especially when you use a `call` to generate data, you are better off using [`table`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#table) and then using a loop:

```
* def data = [{ cityA: 'a', cityB: 'b' }, { cityA: 'c', cityB: 'd' }]
* call read('re-usable.feature') data
```

So please read: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features, you still need 2 feature files, but the sequence of execution is "reversed".

Otherwise, I still don't understand your test. The only way to work around the lack of "dynamicism" in the cells of an `Examples` table is like this:

```
Scenario Outline:
* def res = { cityA: 'foo' }
* def value = <fromLocation>
* match value == 'foo'

Examples:
| fromLocation |
| res.cityA |
```

Refer: [`examples.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/examples.feature) - the last example.

But hopefully you will understand that you are using `Examples` the wrong way which will confuse all the people who need to read your test in the future. If you still have questions, ask a new one - and this time give some summary of the use-case you are trying to automate.

EDIT: see `@setup` that gives you a way to set the whole of `Examples` in a dynamic way: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#setup