# Dynamic Payload passing through Example Keyword in Karate DSL

Tags: karate

I have 4 different payloads for the same API(Filter API), Wanted to use parametrization using Scenario Outline.

1)

```
{
   "page_size":20,
   "start_index":0,
   "metadata_filters":[
      {
         "id":"coaching_session",
         "values":[
            "present"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

2. 

```
{
   "page_size":20,
   "start_index":0,
   "metadata_filters":[
      {
         "id":"coaching_session",
         "values":[
            "present"
         ]
      }
   ],
   {
      "id":"supervisor_evaluation",
      "values":[
         "present"
      ]
   }
]
}
```

3)metadata_filters:

```
[
   {
      "id":"coaching_session",
      "values":[
         "present"
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"supervisor_evaluation",
      "values":[
         "present"
      ]
   },
   "...."
]
}
}
```

4. 

```
{
   "page_size":20,
   "start_index":0
}
```

I am trying to automate using Karate DSL

Can some guide me through the approach?

Comment: short answer, don't: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475 - but also see the answer linked as duplicate

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60499447/143475

Comment: @PeterThomas, So you are saying that I should create 4 different scenarios (test case) and test it right?

Comment: that is one of the options (which I personally prefer). it is up to you once you read and understand the links above.