# DRY or DAMP - Which one is efficient in API automation test scripts?

Tags: rest, automated-tests, karate

I am currently writing REST API automation test scripts. As most of the research article suggests that we should write **DAMP (Descriptive And Meaningful Phrases)** tests that promote readability. However, I feel that there are a lot of duplicate codes in my tests and in an attempt to remove the duplicates I end up with '**DRY**' (Don't repeat yourself) code which tends to dependency tests. So I am a bit confused about which approach to use? I would really appreciate it If anyone can give me some suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendations are:

- re-use payloads (JSON or XML) from files where possible
- sign-in flows that set an `Authorization` header should be re-usable
- do not combine API requests to different end-points into a re-usable `Scenario`
- even for the same end-point, for very different payloads (e.g. boundary / error conditions) use a separate `Scenario` for each
- use `Scenario Outlines` for data-driven tests

Also please refer this answer for a good example of what NOT to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Answer (score 2):

A general rule is to keep the code related to the *Test Objective* **DAMP**, having everything else **DRY**.
To simplify the rule, code related to the *Test Objective* may reference to:

- Actions that **DIRECTLY** impact the expected result
- Data parameters that **DIRECTLY** affect the expected result

Code NOT related to the *Test Objective* may reference to:

- Actions that do not impact the expected result **DIRECTLY** 
  *(Example: authorization for the tests not related to login)*
- Configuration data and data parameters that does not affect the expected results **DIRECTLY** 
  *(Example: Base URL, login and password for the tests not related to authorization)*