# Karate does not seem to retain xml format in few scenarios

Tags: karate

I tried following:

```
def isJson = false
xml payload_xml = read(some.xml)
json payload_json = read(some.json)
def payload = isJson == true ? payload_json : payload_xml

Given url someURL
Given request payload
When method post
```

turns out the payload is now payload_xml but in json format.

Also when I use single xml payload to consecutively call same abstract feature which has

```
Given url someURL
Given request payload
When method post
```

the second time payload is in json format.

Are there issues or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will *always* return JSON, because Karate will default JS evaluation like so:

```
* def payload = isJson == true ? payload_json : payload_xml
```

So figure out another approach. I feel you are over-complicating your test, and I recommend splitting into 2 scenarios. Please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

There is no way to conditionally cast JSON to XML. You can work-around by calling a second feature. If you still see issues, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT: maybe all you need to do is this:

```
* def payload == isJson == true ? read('some.json') : read('some.xml')
```

EDIT2: this will be easier in 0.9.6 onwards:

a) https://stackoverflow.com/a/62856565/143475

b) https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1202