# karate : handling soap response from a called feature file

Tags: karate

**first.feature**
Given ur ''

- def payload = read('')
- request payload
- soap action ''
- value = /Envelope/Body/Response/Result/Num
- print value # prints value correctly as expected

**second.feature**
Background:
*def fetch = read('first.feature')
*def data = call fetch

Scenario:

- print data.response # prints the soap response in json format.
- def res = data.response
- print res["s:Envelope"]["*"]["s:Body"]["Response"]["*"]["Result"]["_"]["a:num']

first.feature works as expected ( response is in soap )
When I try to call this feature in another feature then the response is in json format.

I want to use a value from this response to pass it on to another request.
I had to use res["s:Envelope"]["_"]["s:Body"][][].. to get to that.

Is there a way to easily fetch a value from this response as we do in first.feature?
Please could anyone let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this change:

```
* xml res = data.response
```

We will be improving this in the next version, it would be good if you can test the `develop` branch and confirm: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: Thanks Peter for your quick response.

Comment: from * xml res I am able fetch the value from soap response by $res /Envelope/Body/.....