How do I interact with XML response keys for a request triggered in other feature file?
I have a .feature file that I call into another feature file using call read(...). This triggers a SOAP request and asserts the status code.
When def reusableRequestCall = call read('classpath:<filePath>.feature') { ... }
Now, I'm trying to interact with the response from reusableRequestCall object in order to save some data for further requests, but I don't find the right solution.
The XML response has this structure:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope     xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  <SOAP-ENV:Body>         <ProcessMessageResponse             xmlns="http://www.redskyit.com">            <ProcessMessageResult>              ...             </ProcessMessageResult>         </ProcessMessageResponse>   </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
I even tried to convert the response to JSON with: * jsonObj = reusableRequestCall.response and the result looks like this:
{   "SOAP-ENV:Envelope": {     "_": {       "SOAP-ENV:Body": {         "ProcessMessageResponse": {           "_": {             "ProcessMessageResult": {               "Parameters": {                 "_": {...
For example, when printing Envelope object with * print jsonObj.Envelope, it prints null.
What is the correct syntax to reference some specific fields within this type of response?
Thank you!

I think you should look at other answers. yes some trial and error with different xpath combinations will be needed: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+xml+xpath

take a look at this post, seems like the exact thing you are trying to do as well :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856243/karate-handling-soap-response-from-a-called-feature-file

@LurkinGherkin, thanks! Your suggestion was helpful.
