# Use conditional logic in Scenario Outline with lists

Tags: karate

We use karate 0.9.5. We would like to make a dynamic Scenario Outline using conditional logic.
We would like to retrieve towns for a list of regions, and this for a list of countries.
Conditional logic is used only in towns retrieving. What we've done:

Main.feature:

```
Scenario Outline:
* def countries = call read('GetRegionsWithTowns.feature') { countryId: '#(<id>)' }
Examples:
  |countriesList|
```

GetRegionsWithTowns.feature:

```
Scenario:
* def fun =
  """
  function(regions) {
    for (i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
      var region = regions[i];
      if(region['name'] && region['name'].contains('alabama')){
        karate.log('***smth');
      }
      else{
        var regionId = region['region_id'];
        karate.call('GetTowns.feature', [regionId]);
      }
    }
  }
  """
* def regions = call read('GetRegions.feature') { countryId: '#(countryId)' }
* def result = call fun(regions)
```

GetRegions.feature

```
Scenario:
 Given url 'someurl'
 And path countryId, 'regions' 
 When method get
 Then status 200
```

GetTowns.feature

```
Scenario:
 Given url 'someurl'
 And path regionId, 'towns'
 When method get
 Then status 200
```

Error is

```
 GetTowns.feature:16 (the line with "And path regionId, 'towns'") - javascript evaluation failed: regionId, ReferenceError: "regionId" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

We can't figure out what we are doing wrong? Any help is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the change needed:

```
karate.call('GetTowns.feature', { regionId: regionId });
```

I do think you are grossly overcomplicating your tests.

- I would try to avoid `call` as far as possible.
- Any variables defined in parent features will be visible to "called" features, so you don't need to pass all data as arguments
- Avoid JS code especially loops as far as possible, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops

Comment: Thank u so much @Peter Thomas, but how we can simplify this test? We need to iterate in amount of countries, regions, towns, which is dynamic and we need a condition in towns retrieving.

Comment: @cygne just my opinion and I don't understand your scenario because it is so complex. sometimes you should just hard-code your input and output data for simpler tests, best explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475