# How to read dynamic data in request payload from json file?

Tags: json, karate, data-driven-tests

Below is my sample one `JSON` file, named as `multiple.json` and I have given the sample structure of my json file.

```
{
    "sample_key":[{"name":"John","salary":"10000","age":"25"}],
    "another_key":[{"author":"Scott","publication":"Pearson","year":"2019"}]
}
```

I have single feature file which has two `Scenario Outline`. This file is reading `JSON` object from `multiple.json` file which contains different `JSON` object separated by key value pair. And I want to pass the data in `request payload` which is `sample_key` and `another_key` in the below feature file.

My `Sample.feature` file:

```
Background:
    * def kittens = read('../json/multiple.json')

Scenario Outline: Create Sample Name Record
Given url url
And request { sample_key:'<sample_key>'}        // Here, I have question..
When method POST
Then status 200
* def output = response
* print output

Examples:
|kittens|

Scenario Outline: Create Sample Author Record
Given url url
And request { another_key:'<another_key>'}      // Here, I have question..
When method POST
Then status 200
* def output = response
* print output

Examples:
|kittens|
```

However, it is working only with below `JSON` with `scenario`.(Here, I do not have added `JSON object in array`)

`{
    "sample_key":{"name":"John","salary":"10000","age":"25"},
    "another_key":{"author":"Scott","publication":"Pearson","year":"2019"}
}`

But it's not working when I give the `JSON object in array` (as mentioned at the top of question)

I want to pass multiple records in a single `sample_key` which I want to run it in a single `scenario`.

So, how can I pass `sample_key in Scenario Outline: Create Sample Name Record`?

Kindly suggest me. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: maybe this is the answer you are looking for:

```
Examples:
| kittens.sample_key |
```

Maybe you don't need a `Scenario Outline` then. You can access JSON by index and just use 2 `Scenario`-s

```
* def sample_key = kittens.sample_key[0]
```

Also note that if you use a dynamic `Scenario Outline` you get an automatic `__num` variable: https://github.com/intuit/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

So you can do this if kittens is a JSON array:

```
* def payload = kittens[__num]
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your response. 
I tried both the approach with `scenario` and with `scenario outline(__num)`. But none of them is working.
However, it is working only with below `JSON` with `scenario`.(Here, I do not have added `JSON object in array`)


`{
    "sample_key":{"name":"John","salary":"10000","age":"25"},
    "another_key":{"author":"Scott","publication":"Pearson","year":"2019"}
}`

Comment: @Rucha sorry, time for you to follow this process, or wait for someone else to help you: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: But, its not working when I give `JSON object in array` like below which is also mentioned in my question.

`{
    "sample_key":[{"name":"John","salary":"10000","age":"25"}],
    "another_key":[{"author":"Scott","publication":"Pearson","year":"2019"}]
}`

Comment: With reference to above `JSON`, I also have similar `JSON` with multiple records, mentioned as below:

`{
    "sample_key":[{"name":"John","salary":"10000","age":"25"},{"name":"Maria","salary":"20000","age":"30"}],
    "another_key":[{"author":"Scott","publication":"Pearson","year":"2019"},{"author":"Jammy","publication":"Oxford","year":"2020"}]
}`

So, basically, I want to pass multiple records in a single `sample_key` which I want to run it in a single `scenario`.

Kindly suggest me. Thank you !!

Comment: @Rucha sorry I'm not reading all these comments. all your answers are in the docs, or follow the process in the link above. all the best.

Comment: Hi @peter, 

I am not able to format my comments. please consider the same and help me with the solution.

Comment: @Rucha you can edit your question. I suggest you keep it DEAD simple and ask only one thing, if you want any hope of getting an answer, also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Rucha doesn't change my answer. I don't understand why you insist on reading `mutiple.json`. just have 2 normal scenarios and hard-code the `request`. you are un-necessarily complicating your test. also read this, and this is my last comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Comment: Hi Peter, I understand what you are trying to explain me. The reason I wanted to include `request payload` into `JSON file` so that in future I can make the necessary changes in a `JSON` file.