# Matching multiple response in a single scenario outline

Tags: karate, data-driven-tests

I want to match multiple `response` of an `API`. Please find below `Scenario Outline`.

```
Background:
* def kittens = read('../sample.json')

Scenario Outline: Create Test1
Given url url
And request <Users>
When method POST
Then status 200
And match response.success.name == <expectedName>
And match response.success.contact.mobile == <expectedMobile>

Examples:
  |Users|expectedName|expectedMobile|
  |kittens.User1|'Micheal'|'123456'|
  |kittens.User2|'Steve'|'998877'|
```

In the above case, I am able to match for 2 fields but I want to validate for more fields, but it is increasing pile of code that I do not want.

Multiple `response` of an `API`:

```
"success": {
   "name": "Micheal",
   "addr": "Tesla road",
   "contact": {
      "mobile": 123456,
      "phone": 4422356
    }
}


"success": {
   "name": "Steve",
   "addr": "Karen Road",
   "contact": {
      "mobile": 998877,
      "phone": 244344
    }
 }
```

I am looking for minimizing the lines of code.

Can you please tell me another way where I can load entire `response` into `expected` and then I will traverse in the `example` section?

Please help me. Thank you !!

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend you don't do this, and the reasons are explained in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Also note instead of going field-by-field, you can use the whole JSON in the `Examples` column, or even pull from a file, see [`examples.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/examples.feature).

You will actually end up with a much more "increasing pile of code" if you go down this path in my sincere opinion.