# Making the same call twice in a row doesn't update the response

Tags: karate

What I'm trying to do is hit a service twice in a row with a post of the same data.  The idea here is to confirm that I can't have duplicate data, so I should get a 422 and a specific message in the response.

The test looked something like this:

```
When javaClient.createFoo(parameters)
And javaClient.createFoo(parameters)
Then status 422
And match $.message == "This is a duplicate."
```

It doesn't have a problem matching the status of the second call, but when I try to match the message (or any part of the response) it compares to the response from the first call.

I've tried making the second call a When, tried checking the status of the first call in between, but there must be something else that I'm missing.

Any ideas? Is there something special I need to do to clear the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the `method` step is called, Karate does not do anything. The use of `javaClient.createFoo()` (whatever that is) suggests that there are some fundamental problems in your use and understanding of Karate.

I suggest keep it simple and just repeat the `method post` with the same payload and it should work as you expect.

Also please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, and also, holy cow, who better to get a response from! I'm currently trying to work with some stuff that was written before I got a hold of it, and it sounds like I need to go back to those who did that work for answers.  I read the article you posted and will definitely keep it in mind going forward!

Comment: @ScottMacDonald phew, I'm glad I didn't vent more in this answer - thanks for looking out for how to improve !