# Can we add more than one statement in an 'If' statement in Karate?

Tags: karate

I want to execute more than 1 statements provided an If condition is true. I want to know whether and how is it achievable in Intuit Karate framework.

In the Karate documentation, I find examples like below all of which have only one statement to be executed if the If condition is satisfied as listed below.

```
if (env == 'dev') karate.configure("ssl", true)

if (responseStatus == 200) karate.call('delete-user.feature')

if (responseStatus == 404) karate.abort()
```

I want to achieve something like below (only a pseudocode representation of my requirement and not as per the actual Karate syntax)

if (responseStatus ==200)

#statement 1

#statement 2

#statement 3

#end of If

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally good tests should never do this. Make sure you read this also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

But here are the 2 possible patterns:

a) use a second feature file:

```
* if (condition) karate.call('second.feature')
```

b) use a function, the disadvantage is only the JS API, things like `match` not supported

```
* def fun = 
"""
function() {
  // line 1
  // line 2
}
"""
* if (condition) fun()
```

Comment: @GautamDas I'm not really interested in the details, I think my answer gives you all the information you need. if there is any specific thing you don't understand, ask a new question please