# Karate : xml is being type casted to json when ternary(?:) operator is used and value assigned to variable declared with def keyword

Tags: karate

I am having two files one is json and one is xml. I want to print json or xml file content on the basis of the `isJson` flag. But I am seeing that when the `isJson == false` its returning the json content from the below program.

```
Scenario: ternary operator over different type files
* def isJson = false
* json jsonFile = {name : 'user'}
* xml xmlFile = <name>user</name>
* def payload = isJson == true ? jsonFile : xmlFile
* print 'payload --->',payload
```

console output :

```
INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] payload ---> {
 "name": "user"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate does try to auto-detect, but can fail sometime to print - but behind the scenes it is XML and you can send / use it normally. I also strongly recommend that you don't write these kinds of dynamic tests. Please read this carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

So you may have to live with this, or please contribute code. Note that if you use `karate.prettyXml()` you can see the variable printed as XML if it is. The next 1.0 version may improve this, but no guarantees.