# How to implement conditional When method in Karate

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I would like to reuse a feature both for POST-ing and PUT-ing a JSON Object. In order to achieve that I am trying to use a condition in the call:

```
Given param admin = admin
And request role
When method (role.id == null) ? karate.POST : karate.PUT
```

The error I get:

> no step-definition method match found for: method (role.id == null) ? karate.POST : karate.PUT

I checked the documentation and the examples and search for the solution here, but I did not find an answer to this question.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable for the `method` step:

```
* def action = 'GET'
* url 'https://httpbin.org/get'
* method action
```

Other than that I have no suggestions. I strongly advise you to not do this kind of "re-use" as it leads to un-readable and un-maintainable tests. Please read this once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Comment: Thanks, Peter. After reading the linked post and following the additional links inside that I am persuaded that I should not do this. By the way, thanks for developing Karate DSL, it is just awesome.

Comment: @MiklósSzeles glad you like it - and thank you for this comment. to be very honest most people don't listen to this particular suggestion, great to hear that you took the time to understand the trade-offs