# Karate - How change key name in JSON

Tags: karate

I have the following JSON. I want to change the keyName 'freeDelivery' to 'isFreeDelivery' but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "deliverySlots": [
                {
                    "id": "2DNN",
                    "date": "2022-04-05",
                    "freeDelivery": false,
                    "label": "All day delivery 08:30am to 5pm",
                    "price": "£5.00",
                    "fullSlotId": "2DNN"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2DPM",
                    "date": "2022-04-05",
                    "freeDelivery": false,
                    "label": "Afternoon 12pm to 5pm",
                    "price": "£10.00",
                    "fullSlotId": "2DPM"
                }
                ]
        },
        {
            "deliverySlots": [
                {
                    "id": "2DNN",
                    "date": "2022-04-06",
                    "freeDelivery": false,
                    "label": "All day delivery 08:30am to 5pm",
                    "price": "£5.00",
                    "fullSlotId": "2DNN"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2DPM",
                    "date": "2022-04-06",
                    "freeDelivery": false,
                    "label": "Afternoon 12pm to 5pm",
                    "price": "£10.00",
                    "fullSlotId": "2DPM"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've looked at the following pages but still can't figure out how to do it. Do I have to do a transorm or is there an easier way?

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/js-arrays.feature
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def payload = { before: 'foo' }
* remove payload.before
* payload.after = 'bar'
* match payload == { after: 'bar' }
```

Instead of `remove` this will also work (using pure JS):

```
* eval delete payload.before
```

EDIT: after seeing the comments, I would treat this as a JSON transform.

```
* def payload = { before: 'foo' }
* def fun = function(x){ var res = {}; res.after = x.before; return res }
* def result = fun(payload)
* match result == { after: 'foo' }
```

I'm sure now you'll want to "retain" all the existing data. Fine, here you go:

```
* def payload = { before: 'foo' }
* def fun = function(x){ var res = x; res.after = x.before; delete res.before; return res }
* def result = fun(payload)
* match result == { after: 'foo' }
```

And you already know that you can run a transform on all array elements like this:

```
* def result = karate.map(someArray, fun)
```

Please note that you can create 2 or 3 transforms - and "nest" them.

Comment: Thanks Peter but I don't want to remove the key I just want to change the key name but keep the value.  Also there are many occurences of 'freeDelivery' keys and I need to change them all. I've added more of the JSON in the question so it makes more sense.

Comment: @Matt see my edit. beyond this if you want simplification, I have only this to say: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Comment: Thanks again @peter. I've managed to change the first occurrence of 'id' by manually entering the json path as shown below...but how can I change all of them? Do I have to loop through them all? Is there an easier way of finding the key without manually entering the full  JSON Path?         * def jsonTransformFunction = function(passedInJson){ var newJson = passedInJson; newJson.result[0].deliverySlots[0].changedId = passedInJson.result[0].deliverySlots[0].id; delete newJson.result[0].deliverySlots[0].id; return newJson }

Comment: @Matt when I say a `transform on all array elements` that *is* a loop. otherwise you are expecting Karate to be a programming language. I have nothing more to add to all the hints that I have provided.