# [karate]: create features with other features that include scenarios outline

Tags: karate

I have a question
Let’s say, I have 2 features in my tests

- example-a.feature that contains an outline scenario with 10 lines
- example-b.feature which contains another outline scenario which also contains 10 lines.

Is it possible to create an example-c.feature from features a and b? If so, is this a good practice?
It seems to me that this can generate a lot of complexity.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be complex. I personally think you should have only one level of "call". There are some thoughts (and rants) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Karate is supposed to be a testing tool not a general-purpose programming language. But like any programming language, it can be misused and used in a way that makes it un-maintainable for anyone who lands in your project in the future. It is up to you to make the right decisions.