# How to set any value from Examples keyword data table to JSON key in Karate

Tags: arrays, json, indexing, integer, karate

In Scenario Outline ,
I want to set,

- set payload.countryName. ==

Examples:

|CountryValue| stateName |

|India       | DL |
|India       | KL |
|USA         | NY |
|India       | MP |

Que: I want to set 3rd row value i.e USA == NY directly without first two row record.How can i do it ?

I am able to pass values from Examples only in sequencial manner and I am able to know how can it be done for any row value to set in json.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, please assume that this is not supported in Karate. I think you have a mis-understanding of `Scenario Outline`. Please read the documentation and look at other examples such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73383069/143475