# Remove Mandatory fields in Request Body as a part of Scenario Outline

Tags: karate

I need to create a scenario outline in which I want to remove the mandatory fields that is required in an API to test for 400 Bad Request

Example:
JSON Body:

```
[
  {
    "context": {
      "x": "{{x}}",
      "y": "{{y}}",
      "z": "{{z}}"
    },
    "oId": "",
    "oIId": ""
  }
]
```

```
Scenario Outline: Validate API - 400 Bad Request with <Comments>
    
    Given url baseUrl + path
    And 
    * set VoidItemFromOrderRequest[0].context.x = x
    * set VoidItemFromOrderRequest[0].context.y = y
    * set VoidItemFromOrderRequest[0].context.z = z
    * eval if (orId == "removefield") { karate.remove('APIRequestBody[0].oId') }
    * eval if (orId != "removefield") { karate.set('APIRequestBody[0].oId', 1) }
    * eval if (orIId == "removefield") { karate.remove('APIRequestBody[0].oIId') }
    * eval if (orIId != "removefield") { karate.set('APIRequestBody[0].oIId', 1) }
    * request APIRequestBody[0]
    When method PUT
    Then status 400
    * match response.errors.reason == reason

Examples:
      |orIId         | orId          | reason                                  | Comments
      | abc          | removefield   | body.oId is required                    | Remove oId
      | removefield  | abc           | body.oIId is required                   | Remove oIId
```

I am getting error in lines eval if as below, how do we fix it?

`org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (remove) on com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge failed due to: Arity error - expected: 2 actual: 1

- .:program(Unnamed:1)`

Scenario Intent:

1. Pass the request body with context & oIId but not with oId
2. Pass the request body with context & oId but not with oIId

FYI -

1. I am not looking for null values to these fields but the requirement is not to send the field itself in request body
2. I can create two separate individual scenarios but looking for optimization here whether its feasible or not

The attempts have been mentioned in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Note that `karate.remove()` takes two arguments, the first being the Karate variable name you are operating on.

Note that in the latest versions of Karate you can directly operate on JS objects:

```
* VoidItemFromOrderRequest[0].context.x = x
```

And `if` will work without eval:

```
* if (orId != "removefield") { karate.set('APIRequestBody[0].oId', 1) }
```

Here is a working example, you can take hints from it, also refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

```
Feature:

Background:
* def data = { dum: 'a', foo: 'b' }

Scenario Outline:
* if (nofoo) karate.remove('data', 'foo')
* if (addbar) karate.set('data', 'bar', 'c')
* print data

Examples:
| nofoo! | addbar! |
| true   | false   |
| false  | true    |
```

And finally, maybe you are overcomplicating things, you can load JSON from `Examples` rows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73383069/143475