# how to access the variable defined in Background section to setup scenario in Karate feature

Tags: karate

Feature: API Testing feature

```
  Background:
    * configure logPrettyRequest = true
    * configure logPrettyResponse = true
    * def data = call read('classpath:Features/GetData.feature')
    * print data // prints the data as expected.

  @setup
  Scenario: get Data from 
   
    * print "data ==>  ",data

    Getting Below error when printing data variable in setup scenario.

    org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "data" is not defined
```

is this feature supported by karate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@setup` cannot use the `Background`, it is [designed to create data "from scratch" and nothing else](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1905#issuecomment-1203597442). You can still use variables from the global config of course. Think of the `@setup` as only a way to create data for a dynamic `Scenario Outline`. Then each row uses a `Background` like normal.

If you are concerned about "re use", my advice is [don't be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475).

If you really want - you can create a re-usable feature, and use it from both the `Background` and `@setup` but I really wouldn't recommend that. Try to design your tests to be simpler and better would be my advice.