# Implement conditional validation based on keys in the map doesn't work as expected

Tags: karate

To implement conditional validation based on keys in the map.

- Defined a map
- Passed map to a function
- Fetched keys of map
- If keyset contains specific string perform specific validation

```
    Scenario: 
    * def validations = { title : "Heading", description: "Actual description"}
    * def conditionalValidation = 
    """
    function(validations){
    var keySet = karate.keysOf(validations);
    if(karate.match("keySet contains 'title'")){
    console.log('Title validation required')}
    else { console.log('Title validation is not required')}
    
    if(karate.match("keySet contains 'subHeading'")){
    console.log('Subheading validation is required')}
    else{ console.log('Subheading validation is not required')}
    } 
    """
    * conditionalValidation(validations)
```

Expected Output:
Title validation required
Subheading validation is not required

Can someone correct where I'm missing things.

Comment: karate is designed to validate JSON and you are not using it the way it is designed. I strongly discourage this kind of approaches, which in my mind is overengineering. please read this answer and re-think your approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Comment: I'm trying to use this approach for UI validations, which are dynamic based on the page.
Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: you are welcome. may I suggest that you get the data from the page, and transform it to json. then just do a single match. here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+html+table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the fix:

replaced
`karate.match("keySet contains 'title'")`
with
`karate.match("keySet contains 'title'").pass`