# Order .json data in Karate test project

Tags: testing, karate

I'm creating an automated test project using the Karate framework.
This project has both UI and API tests.
Initially, I've organized my tests by feature and each folder has a json file for each environment to manage the dataset.

I realize that I'm going to have a lot of duplicate data between my API tests and my UI tests. I was wondering if there are any best practices on data management to get a clear and scalable architecture on test data.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are already set if you are using JSON files. You can always try to do more "centralization" of data, but keep in mind that it may come [at a cost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475).