# Karate call embedded function conditionally

Tags: karate

I wrote an embedded function inside my feature file and on a conditional basis, I want to call the function only if the first object of the data array doesn't match dataNotFound
definition.

Aprreciate your help.

Scenario: xxxxxx

#Getting data array from DB

- def lenArray = data.length
- def deleteTokens =
  """
  function(lenArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i<lenArray; i++) {
  karate.call('deleteTokensCreated.feature', {ownerId: data[i].owner_id, token: data[i].token});
  }
  }
  """

  - def dataNotFound = {"message": "Data not found!"}
  - def deletedTokens = call deleteTokens lenArray

**"* eval if (data[0] != dataNotFound ) call deleteTokens lenArray"** doesn't work.

Please, consider I am a business analyst who is trusted with test automation task and has no prior experience with either Java or Karate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate deliberately limits the amount of "logic" you can introduce, please read this for some context, and it may help you navigate this new world better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Here's how I would write your scenario, I hope it gets you going:

```
* def fun = function(){ karate.log('hello world') }
* def data = [{ message: 'not found' }, {message: 'foo'}, {message: 'bar'}]
* if (data[0].message === 'not found') fun()
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for guiding. I solved it defining a variable as follows: * def deletedTokens = data[0].message == 'Data not found!' ? dataNotFound : deleteTokens(lenArray)