evaluate response value against table of intial, updated, and expected value
We are looking to create a single table for reference, that we can use to validate a result (opStatus after update applied), based on the initial value (currentStatus pulled from previous request) the updated value (serviceLevel applied update).  While we can create numerous if statements, I hope there is a more efficient way to evaluate the respose.
    * table data
    | currentStatus              | serviceLevel | opStatus          |
    | Connected                  | basicService | Suspended         |
    | Connected                  | noService    | Suspended         |
    | Connected                  | fullService  | Connected         |
    | Offline                    | basicService | Offline_Suspended |
    | Offline                    | noService    | Offline_Suspended |
    | Offline                    | fullService  | Offline           |
    | Suspended                  | fullService  | Connected         |
    | Suspended                  | basicService | Suspended         |
    | Suspended                  | noService    | Suspended         |
    | Connected                  | fullService  | Connected         |
    | Connected                  | basicService | Suspended         |
    | Connected                  | noService    | Suspended         |
    | Offline_Suspended          | fullService  | Offline           |
    | Offline_Suspended          | basicService | Offline_Suspended |
    | Offline_Suspended          | noService    | Offline_Suspended |
    | Pending_Suspension         | basicService | Suspended         |
    | Pending_Suspension         | noService    | Suspended         |
    | Pending_Suspension         | fullService  | Connected         |
    | Offline_Pending_Suspension | basicService | Offline_Suspended |
    | Offline_Pending_Suspension | noService    | Offline_Suspended |
    | Offline_Pending_Suspension | fullService  | Offline           |

sample excerpt from response we are trying to compare against
  "service": {
    "alpha": {
      "serviceCode": [
        "123456",
        "abcdef"
      ],
      "baseServiceCode": "baseServiceCode",
      "category": "Internet",
      "opStatus": "CONNECTED",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "resources": [
        {
          "model": "TestModel",
          "ssid": "SpectrumSetup-TestModel",
          "serial": "FAKESERIALNUM00",
          "opStatus": "CONNECTED",
          "admStatus": "ACTIVE",
          "macAddr": "0011223344ff",
          "resourceId": "0011223344ff"
        }
      ]
    }


This is one way to do it, all the concepts you need are captured. The core concept is to write a function that is able to loop over all your combinations and find the right one. Keep in mind that behind the scenes, data is a JSON array, you can * print data to look at it. Then normal JS concepts apply, take the help of someone who knows JS well if needed.
* table data
| arg1 | arg2 | result |
| 'a'  | 'b'  | 1      |
| 'a'  | 'c'  | 2      |

* def lookup = function(v1, v2){ return data.find(x => x.arg1 == v1 && x.arg2 == v2) }
# test if our custom lookup function works
# * match lookup('a', 'b') == { arg1: 'a', arg2: 'b', result: 1 }

* def currentStatus = 'a'
* def response = { serviceLevel: 'c', opStatus: 2 }
* def expected = lookup(currentStatus, response.serviceLevel)
* match response.opStatus == expected.result

For the benefit of others that may be seeing this answer, I do NOT recommend adding logic to tests like this, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Thank you for the assist.  As a side note, is it possible to supress the table from being outputted in the karate report?

@mike you may be able to move it into a called feature and put a @report=false annotation, also refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#report-verbosity

thanks.  I moved the table to a separate called feature, but when setting the report=falase tag at the feature or scenario level in that file, the reporting stops from that point forward, in the original feature file

i worked around this by creating a second scenario in the called feature file, with a report = true tag like this `Feature:Data table for permutations of oscStatus enumerations
@report=false
Scenario: permutation table
* table data
| currentStatus                | desiredOnlineStatus | opStatus                     |
...table data removed...
@report=true
Scenario:
#turn reporting back on`

@mike yeah that sounds like a bug. the other approach which is to do * configure report = false and then later * configure report = true may be the best solution

Was a bug created for this issue?  Any thoughts of a release?
