How to pass path and params from a feature fiile to a generalised scenario
I am using karate framework for my automation testing. In that i have written the below generalised scenario and all values are parameterised.
    @holder
    Scenario: 
    Given url SampleURL
    And path SamplePath
    And params SampleParam
    When method GET
    Then status 200

I am trying to call this holder scenario from a feature file:
    Scenario:
    And call read('Sample.feature@holder'){SampleURL: 'https://example.com', SamplePath: '',SampleParam: ''}

However, i wanted to pass the path and params also dynamically if we have anything, if we don't have anything I am trying to pass the empty string. Somehow it is not working even if i gave empty string '/' is appending at the end and the scenario is failing.
How can we pass the path and params (if we have multiple) dynamically?
Thanks in advance.

this person has never accepted an answer on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Thanks for reminding me. I accepted some answers that helped me debug and fix several issues. Can you please help me fix the above issue

I'll leave it to others to answer this question. but let me say that trying to "generalize" scenarios is a bad idea and I strongly suggest that you don't do it. please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

I set your secnario into an outline to show all scenarios working.  Essentially, you need to set your empty params variable to a json string.
Feature:

  @holder
  Scenario:
    Given url SampleURL
    And path SamplePath
    And params SampleParams
    When method GET
    Then status 200

  Scenario Outline:
    And call read('sample.feature@holder'){SampleURL: '#(SampleURL)', SamplePath: '#(SamplePath)' ,SampleParams: '#(SampleParams)'}

    Examples:
    | SampleURL           | SamplePath! | SampleParams! |
    | https://example.com | ''          | {}            |
    | https://example.com | 'x'         | {}            |
    | https://example.com | ''          | {myParam:'x'} |
    | https://example.com | 'x'         | {myParam:'x'} |

