Error in Karate v1.2 org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: instantiate
Was using Karate v 0.9.6 on the below code and it worked fine. However, facing issues after upgrading to 1.2
As per our current structure, a feature file calls another common feature file which in-turn references a Java Class
Test.feature:
Feature: TestFeature1

  Background:
    * def dataSet= read('classpath:../../TestPayloads.json')

  Scenario Outline: TestCase1- 
    Given print <payload>
    Given def payload = <payload>
    Given def expected = <expected>
    Given karate.call('classpath:Validate.feature')
    Examples:
      | payload          | expected |                                                   
      | dataSet.value[2] | 'PASSED' |

Validate.feature:
Feature: Validator

  Scenario: TestCaseValidator
    Then print 'Started'
    * def Launcher = Java.type('com.test.rest.launcher.Launcher')
    Then print 'the payload is------',payload
    * def execution = new Launcher(payload).start()
    * def validateWith = new Launcher(execution,expected,'~').validate()
    * print execution

Launcher.java:
    public class Launcher { 
            public Launcher(List<String> userArgs) {
            }
        
            public Launcher(String expected, String result,String delimeter) {
            }
        
            public Launcher(LinkedHashMap<String,String> userArgs) {
            }
        
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            }
            
            public String start() {
            }
        
            public String validate() {   
            }
      }

Working on a project structure that is already built and being used. Not sure how this worked well for v0.9.6. But after the upgrade seeing the below error

     Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: js failed:
        >>>>
        01: karate.call('classpath:Validate.feature')
        <<<<
        org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js failed:
        >>>>
        01: new Launcher(payload).start()
        <<<<
        org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: instantiate on com.infa.products.ldmqatest.scanners.rest.launcher.Launcher failed due to: no applicable overload found (overloads
    : [Method[public com.test.rest.launcher.Launcher(java.util.LinkedHashMap)], Method[public com.test.rest.launcher.Launcher(java.l
    ang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)], Method[public com.test.rest.launcher.Launcher(java.util.List)]], arguments: [dataSet[2] (Stri
    ng)])
        - <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
        classpath:/Validate.feature:7


I did try to pass the dataSet[2] as
    Given karate.call('classpath:Validate.feature',{passedString:payload)


And recieved it as
    * def payload = passedString
    * def execution = new Launcher(payload).start()

But this did not help in resolving this issue.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!!

there is no support for old versions of karate. this also looks like an example of someone creating an un-necessary test-framework using karate. this has never been recommended, refer this for why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475 - there are plenty of ways to do data-driven testing in karate that don't require all this java mess: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78673358/143475

@PeterThomas, I understand it's a total mess . Sadly it has been designed this way and there is a huge chuck of scenarios added. Reverting them to the right design is a  tedious job and takes considerate amount of time. Any workaround that you can please suggest which I can get it working for now?
Thanks

@PeterThomas, I'm also trying to understand how this worked in v0.9.6, when I pass the payload from Test.feature and using it in "* def execution = new Launcher(payload).start()" , what it type of "payload" here? Because we never got an overload error

0.9.6 is years out of date and since we published detailed release notes, most teams have been able to upgrade smoothly. I have no idea about Launcher or payload, it seems very specific and proprietary to your project
