How to fetch response code from JS function in karate?
Please find below scenario:
Scenario: Validate API that triggered while updating close out time
    And path '/closeout-settings/closeout-edit'
    * header Cookie = cookieSession
    When method PUT
    * def getResponseMessage =
      """
      function(mid, value){
      var response = [];
        if(value==null)
        {
          response[0]=200;
          response[1] = {
            "mid": mid,
            "lastUpdatedTimestamp": Date.now()
          }
          return response;
        }
        else{
        response[0] = 400;
        response[1] = {"message":null,"responseCode":"CLOSEOUT_SETTINGS_NOT_EDITABLE","internal":null}
          return response;
        }
      }
      """
    * def getResponse = getResponseMessage(data.regressionMid, data.timestamp)[0]
    * def getResponseMessage = getResponseMessage(data.regressionMid, data.timestamp)[1]
    And print getResponse
    And print getResponseMessage
    Then status getResponse
    And match response == getResponseMessage

While running the above code, getting below error response message
Then status getResponse
no step-definition method match found for: status getResponse

can some one please help how to validate response code on the basis of value returning from JS.

these kinds of tests are absolutely not recommended because of reasons explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475 - I don't even understand what that getResponseMessage function is trying to do, let's hope someone else here has the answers

Actually before this I am running a get api , and in case get api returns a value as null, this api will be able to update the setting. Else it will return 400 because it is already updated. Due to this , I created a function to fetch that value.

I have nothing to add to my first comment
