# How to get Gatling Karate Simulation response

Tags: karate

```
val protocol = karateProtocol()

val create = scenario("create").exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/cats-create.feature"))

setUp(
create.inject(rampUsers(10) over (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol)
)
```

For the code above, it is using Gatling to simulate karate service. Is there a way that I can get the http response and store it into a json file? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to write to a text file using Karate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591724/is-there-a-way-to-write-to-a-text-file-using-karate)