# How to use relative or absolute file path in Karate.write function

Tags: karate

I am trying to write my contents into an external file. How to define your file path in the Karate.write(value, file) ?? (I am aware that it is not recommended from the framework perspective but I have to do some JMS activity with my customised Java functions. That is why I am trying to do this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone coming across this answer in the future, *please* read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475

Even if you need to do JMS, I don't understand why you need to write a file. Read the above link again if you need to please. Also Karate has support for async and we even have a JMS example here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#consumer-provider-example

Finally: my strong advice to you: write a Java or JS utility yourself. Look at this example for hints: [`upload.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload.feature) especially this part:

```
* def FileChecker = Java.type('com.intuit.karate.demo.util.FileChecker')
# example of parsing a string into json by karate
* json fileInfo = FileChecker.getMetadata(id)
```

Here we are reading a file, but you get the idea.