# Karate.write overwrites the data, Is there a way where data can be appended with a property

Tags: karate

Karate.write overwrites the data, Is there a way where data can be appended with a property.

```
var file = 'RnRs.txt';
var data = "Scenario Name: " +name+ "Request: " +request+ "; Response: " +response;
karate.write(data, file);
```

I am using this function to generate samples in a required format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Advanced write use-cases have to be implemented by yourself, it will take only a few lines of Java code.

Read this for why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475