# Karate: Multipart file : read works but passing content in value fails

Tags: karate

I have a endpoint with a multipart request which takes two files as part of the request parameter.
I tried with the below snippet with read and it worked, but my use case is to take content from a file and pass it to the value parameter.
Can I pass the content as a file?

The working code if my I try to read the file from directory is

Working feature::

```
Scenario:
* configure headers = {'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization': 'Bearer sgahshshshs'}
Given url "http://filecompare.com/compare"
And multipart file oldfile = { read: './oldfile.json', filename: 'oldfile.json'}
And multipart file newfile = { read: './newfile.json', filename: newfile.json'}
When method post
Then status 200
```

Not working feature::

```
Scenario:
Given url "http://download-oldfile/oldfile"
When method get
* def oldfile = response
Given url "http://download-newfile/newfile"
When method get
* def newfile = response
* configure headers = {'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization': 'Bearer sgahshshshs'}
Given url "http://filecompare.com/compare"
And multipart file oldfile = { value: '#(oldfile)', filename: 'oldfile.json'}
And multipart file newfile = { value: '#(newfile)', filename: newfile.json'}
When method post
Then status 200
```

The contents are printed correctly but api returns error when I use value

Please let me know if I am missing something as part of running with the value keyword in multipart file.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't think of anything other than try to convert the value to a string:

```
* string oldfile = response
```

If still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks, I used the karate.write to save the file and then passed the saved file to the read method.

Comment: @NachiK please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, resolved without needing to save to file by defining a variable holding the JSON object and using set to manipulate its value.

In your case this would look like:

```
* def temp = {value: '', filename: 'oldfile.json'}
* set temp.value = oldFile
#[...]
And multipart file oldFile = temp
```

Comment: there is a bug in 1.0 and 1.1 refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1710#issuecomment-895369103