# Convert JSON to CSV and create .CSV file

Tags: cucumber, karate

Convert Json into CSV file and pass that ids in API parameter

```
  Scenario Outline: get Attribute ID's present in DB
    * def attributeids = db.readRows('SELECT PdmarticleattributeID FROM cs_pdmarticleattribute LIMIT 5')
    * print attributeids
    Given path 'admin/rest/product.json/attribute/'
    And path <PdmarticleattributeID>
    When method get
    Then status 200
    Examples: 
    |read('data/attributeids.csv')|
```

The response of attributeids is as below

```
[
  {
    "PdmarticleattributeID": 42180
  },
  {
    "PdmarticleattributeID": 42179
  },
  {
    "PdmarticleattributeID": 42178
  },
  {
    "PdmarticleattributeID": 42182
  },
  {
    "PdmarticleattributeID": 42181
  }
]
```

is this possible with Karate API?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a CSV with `karate.toCsv()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-tocsv

After that writing it is your responsibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475