# [karate]Unable to read csv file generated by calling feature file

Tags: api, automation, karate

I want to automate a scenario, where csv file generated by first feature file will be the input for second file.

I have created a js function which generate test.csv , I have call this function in setup.feature and then using karate-config.js I have called

karate.callSingle('classpath:apiTest/features/setup_data.feature');

However if i am using test.csv file in my test feature file using

Examples:
|read('classpath:apiTest/testData/test.csv')|

I am getting this error.

com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: test.feature:17 - could not find or read file: classpath:apiTest/testData/test.csv

Does anyone have any idea if this possible in karate.

Comment: read the linked answer. if that does not help, please assume that this is not supported in karate

Comment: Thanks peter thomas for your response, just wanted to confirm Is it not possible to use the csv file generated from first feature file into second feature file because the same csv file when i am using to execute only second feature file, the test is getting passed however this issue is only coming when i am executing both the features in suite

Comment: I have nothing more to add to what is written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475