# How to take screenshot and save it with a current date and time in Karate UI Automation Framework

Tags: testing, automation, screenshot, ui-automation, karate

How to take screenshot and save it with a current date and time in Karate UI Automation.

Answer (score 0):

The [`screenshot()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#screenshot) API actually returns a Java byte-array.

What you do with that byte-array is up to you. The [`karate.write()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475) usage is just an example, please use some custom code if needed.

```
* def bytes = screenshot(false)
* def file = karate.write(bytes, 'test.png')
* print 'screenshot saved to:', file
```