# Export jsMap as json

Tags: karate

I want to export a JsMap (made with `karate.merge`) as a json file, using `karate.write`. My problem is that the file only consists of one line:

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

While I expect something like this (formatted over 4 lines):

```
{
  "a":1,
  "b":2
}
```

My code, with all the conversions I tried (which led to the same result):

```
  Scenario: merge
    * def foo = { a: 1 }
    * def bar = karate.merge(foo, { b: 2 })
    * match bar == { a: 1, b: 2 }
    * karate.write(bar, 'bar1.json')
    * karate.write(bar, 'bar2.txt')
    * karate.write(karate.toJson(bar), 'bar3.json')
    * karate.write(karate.toJson(bar), 'bar4.txt')
    * string bar = bar
    * karate.write(bar, 'bar5.json')
    * karate.write(bar, 'bar6.txt')
    * karate.write(karate.toJson(bar), 'bar7.json')
    * karate.write(karate.toJson(bar), 'bar8.txt')
```

What would be the correct conversion to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you what you want:

```
* def data = {"a":1,"b":2}
* def file = karate.write(karate.pretty(data), 'test.json')
* print 'saved to:', file
```

Karate is not really to be seen as a JSON formatting tool, so consider Java interop if needed. And `karate.write()` has some caveats, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475