# Karate response is overwriting for parallel scenarios

Tags: api, karate, graphql-java, feature-file

I am trying below to execute my test case but not working properly.

While running 2-3 graphql post request scenarios in a single feature file with parallel run enable
and printing the response individually after every post hit.

Then
in every print statement of response I am getting same response (may be the last executed scenario). Hence it is overwriting the response variable and getting same response in all the scenarios of feature file.

Please suggest some way by which I can get response data of individual scenario before overwriting it by another scenario in parallel run.

Thanks

Comment: dev of Karate here. nothing I can do here unless you follow the process to replicate this problem. please note that no one else seems to have this issue. and you can always write a custom utility to "print" whatever that means: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475

Answer (score 0):

Karate has been used by a lot of teams now. So I urge you double-check, who knows - Karate may have surfaced an actual issue in your server where it cannot handle concurrent requests !

This can also happen when you depend on a 3rd party Java utility or custom code that is not thread-safe.

So the best thing you can do is follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue