# Is there any way to save response of each iteration of Scenario Outline to a variable and consolidate all the responses into a single json file

Tags: json, karate, consolidation

[image]I'm trying to save the json response of each iteration of the Scenario Outline and consolidate all the responses into a single json file. But i'm unable to save it in the current feature file nor in any other feature file. Is there any solution to this problem. I tried saving the response to a text file using java which is working fine. But i dont want to make use of files which is not advisable. Is there any better way to do this? Any suggestions would help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Scenario Outline` does not give you any control of "before" and "after" the  entire set of `Examples`.

So please consider an alternative approach to "loop" which will give you what you want: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#data-driven-features

If that doesn't help, please assume that what you want is not supported by Karate. Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475