# can not write response of post request in karate log file

Tags: logging, karate

When I try to karate.log(response) in the feature file, the log is not being written in the karate.log but it is being shown in karate report. But the issue in report is that it is showing as an karate.log([object]) in the report. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Note: when i try karate.log('Post') it is also not getting written in karate.log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is an old version of Karate. Else it is a bug, so please follow this process to help us fix it: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Note that you should not do any string concatenation. For example:

```
karate.log('response:', response);
```

Comment: 1.2.0 is the version I am using

Comment: @ZaeemAhmed I have no other suggestions, you can read this also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475