# How can I dynamically modify a file before passing it to karate.toJavaFile?

Tags: javascript, java, xml, file, karate

Seeing that karate.toJavaFile expects a path, is there any way I can modify a base file before providing it as parameter to the method?

For example, I have this xml in a file:

`<object> <id>123</id> <name>Bob</name> </object>`

Thing is, I need to replace the 123 in the id field with a real id which I get from another GET request before providing this file to the karate.toJavaFile. I'm unfortunately bounded by a Java method.

I tried reading the xml into a variable then modifying its content with * set, but that doesn't help since I need to provide a path and not a variable to karate.toJavaFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would try to achieve what you eventually want to do without writing any file. As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475

But you should be able to do this by saving a temp file:

```
* def data = <foo>bar</foo>
* set data/bar = 'baz'
* def file = karate.write(data, 'temp.xml')
```

Won't that work ?  `karate.write()` returns a `java.io.File` instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This works brilliantly, with the temporary file.

Comment: it seems to somehow transform my xml into a json. Am I doing something wrong?

   ` * def data = read('xmlFile.xml')    
    * set data //fieldName = 'stuff to modify'
    * def file = karate.write(data, 'temp.xml')`

Comment: @CosminCîrstea read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion - so this should work: `* xmlstring dataString = data` and then save that

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed. You are right, I did not understand type conversion too well initially, but I took a more in depth look into it now.

Everything works as expected. Thank you very much for the support and the great stuff in Karate!